# About using Aggregate

Tags: c#

```
string[] fruits = { "apple", "mango", "orange", "passionfruit", "grape" };
```

I want it not to take the last value in this string.

However, if there is only 1 value in the array, it may be an error if it does not take the last value as follows, so if there is 1 value in the array, it should take it. I want to put / between words. Is there an easy way to do this?

string[] fruits = { "apple" };

For example:

I output at string 1 : apple/mango/orange/passionfruit
I got out on the 2nd string: apple

The last value in the 1st string is missing as you can see. but if 1 value remains in the string it should still show in the output

Comment: "I want it not to take the last value in a string like this" - A string like what? "But it should only take if there is one value" - what should only take? What do you mean by one value? Please rephrase your question to provide more clarity.

Comment: It's not really clear what are you asking about. Please read [ask]. Maybe you are looking for [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0).

Comment: I see you've edited your question and it sounds like you are trying to do something like `fruits.join("/")`. Will you please provide expected output for different inputs?

Answer (score 1):

```
string s = string.Join("/", fruits[fruits.Length > 1 ? ..^1 : ..]);
```

As per your edit '*the last value in the 1st string is missing as you can see*' - I think this is the solution you need.

We use a Range object to return the desired values from the fruits array. We use a ternary operator to determine the behaviour - if there is more than one element we return all values except the last (Range ..^1), else we return all values (Range ..).

Finally we string.Join the result with "/" for the output you describe.

Comment: Ha, range operator is pretty nice actually :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
string.Join('/', fruits.Take(1).Concat(fruits.Skip(1).Take(fruits.Length - 2)))
```

Here `.Take(1)` makes sure that you always taking first element, `fruits.Skip(1).Take(fruits.Length - 2)` excludes the last  and first element (to not have duplicated first one) and `.Concat` combines these into the correct result.

Might not be the best optimal way, but one liner without any conditions and checks